# Load Certificate with Private Key in Windows Runtime

Tags: windows-runtime, certificate

I am trying to load a Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.Certificate from a .DER file that is packaged in a UWP application. Reading [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.certificate#Constructors_) only tells me that the ctor is expecting a DER encoded certificate. I attempted to create this certificate using openssl, but I've noticed that whenever I load a certificate from the constructor it loses the key.

How should I load a certificate from a file in a UWP application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with UWP applications but according to the documentation the constructor for [Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.certificate#Constructors) expects only certificate and not PKCS#12 certificate with private key. The documentation mentions .cer (certificate without private key) and .p7b (certificate or certificate chain in PKCS#7 container).

What you could do is import certificate and private key to the user store by using method [ImportPfxDataAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.certificateenrollmentmanager#Windows_Security_Cryptography_Certificates_CertificateEnrollmentManager_ImportPfxDataAsync_System_String_System_String_Windows_Security_Cryptography_Certificates_ExportOption_Windows_Security_Cryptography_Certificates_KeyProtectionLevel_Windows_Security_Cryptography_Certificates_InstallOptions_System_String_System_String_) or other overload of this method. Then you could fetch the certificate from certificate store using method [FindAllAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.certificatestores#Windows_Security_Cryptography_Certificates_CertificateStores_FindAllAsync_Windows_Security_Cryptography_Certificates_CertificateQuery_).

Comment: Thank you. This is what I ended up doing.